# I've only programmed in AS3; What's the easiest practice in Flash CS4 to create simple animations?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

So I've been using Flash for awhile, but rarely ever use the authoring tool. I want to create  a quick little slideshow in which a user clicks buttons, and assets on the screen fade in an out as you move from slide to slide. I don't want to do this programatically...what's the quickest route to go about doing this, with using some AS3 but primarily relying on CS4's authoring tools? I remember when I first learned flash, years ago, you placed elements on stage and stretched them out over multiple frames. That seems like a lot of work...I'd rather just have, say, 10 total frames, each frame being a step in the slideshow, and each click of the next button going to that next frame, with each frame having its own animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should work with framescripts, flash IDE also gives you this possibility to code while you make frame animations. This way you will take the most advantage of working in the IDE.